Simplify an algebraic expression containing powers
I'm trying to simplify the following kind of expression:
(-a)^(-((1 + m)/m)) a^(-1/m)

I would like to receive something like:
(-1)^(-((1 + m)/m)) a^(-((2 + m)/m))

I am receiving nothing but
(-a)^(-((1 + m)/m)) a^(-1/m)

I tried to use refine to include assumptions following what I read in different questions on this forum. This is my attempt:
Refine[ (a)^(-1/m)  (-a)^(-((1 + m)/m)), {a != 0, b != 0,m > 1}] // FullSimplify 

It didn't work as well. How can I do that? I must say that this is just part of the problem. I would like to apply this strategy when $a=1 - 2 c z^r + z^{2 r}$ but decided to face this simpler situation first before next step.

Are you happy with the following result?
(-a)^(-((1 + m)/m)) a^(-1/m);

Simplify[PowerExpand[%]]


